# C# ASP.Net Consolidated DB with Membership Provider configured with aspnet_regsql.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, membership-provider

I attemped to consolidate the MembershipProvider DB with my existing DB using the following command:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S <server> -E -d <database> -A all
```

The executable finished successfully but when I look at the existing DB, I don't see the additional tables for the MembershipProvider.  I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 (not SQLExpress).  Is there something else I need to do?

I reran the executable from the aspnet_regsql.exe wizard and had the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try and run it via the wizard, by just executing `aspnet_regsql.exe` (no parameters) maybe the command line version is committing some errors.

Comment: Are you using integrated security or sql auth? Does the user have the right to create tables on that particular database? Do you have more than one SQL Server instance installed?

Comment: I'm using Integrated Security and I am the administrator (this is running on my home personal computer).  I do have 2 SQL instances but DB is only on the instance I am referencing and the executable is finding the DB.

Comment: Very strange. You could use the SQL Profiler to see whether the commands actually reach the db and if so why they don't cause any tables to be created. Are you using the newest version of the aspnet_regsql.exe, meaning the .NET 4 one? Maybe the others are not compatible with SQL 2008 R2?

Comment: As far as the version of aspnet_regslq.ext, probably not ... this is an older tutorial that I'm using.  Good catch.  I will check that.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me how to use Sql-Profiler?  I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: I was just thinking, if I'm using the Wizard, wouldn't that automatically use the correct version of aspnet_regsql?

Comment: No. The wizard is simply shown when the executable is called without parameters. Try the one in: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`

Comment: I tried using the version 4 and had the same result ... no membership provider tables were added. ;o((